# How can I make a database field have a default value in OpenERP7?

Tags: openerp-7

Assume I have this model:

```
class my_model(orm.Model):
    _name = 'my.model'
    _columns = {
        'my_field': fields.selection([('a', 'A'), ('b', 'B'), ('c', 'C')], string="My Field", required=True, ...)
    }

    _defaults = {
        'my_field': 'a'
    }
```

But when the table is created, the column has not a default value (this means: If I execute `insert into my_model(id) values (1)`, the value 'a' will not be populated on field `my_field`, but an error for `my_field` having a null value when it is not null will be raised).

How can I make -without manually adding the setting by sql- my field have a DEFAULT setting in SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are add record by using **sql query** then this is impossible to set default value.

but you can alter table structure by executing another query execute in **init** method or **separate action**.

Query :

```
ALTER TABLE my_model
   ALTER COLUMN my_field SET DEFAULT 'a';
```

and now you get default value for my_field form sql command

For more information  [PostgreSQL Default Values](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/ddl-default.html)

Comment: I wanted to avoid explicit SQL calls, but it seems that I'm forced to use it.